# Nginx server doesn't serve GET requests with parameters on EC2 instance

Tags: nginx

I've got my nginx server running a php8.0 and Laravel 8.0 web app on an ec2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04.
So the web app works just fine, I can access the DB, look up data and insert new data, all the requests for this things are POST or GET requests with no params. But when I try to do GET requests that have parameters the app just shows a white screen, like nothing is happening. For example:

This GET request doesn't work:

http://mypublicamazonurl.com/clients-update?id=2&client_name=John&client_last_name=Doe&client_email=johndoe%40gmail.com&client_phone_number=9999&action=update

This GET request does work:

http://mypublicamazonurl.com/labels

My server conf file looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/Proyecto-Final-IAW/las-olivas/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 'mypublicurl.com' 'www.mypublicurl.com';

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

This is my very first time setting a server so any help/tip is appreciated and hopefully I was clear.

Comment: A "white screen" means there's an error. Check your logs.

Comment: @miken32 I've checked nginx logs, psql logs, laravel logs and I see nothing. Checking the browser console in the network section I get a 200 status from the request, so looks like nothing wrong is happening.

Comment: So I "fixed" this by making all GET requests with params into POST requests, so the url doesnt have 'anything' on it. I know it's not the correct way, but I'll keep it as long as it works and I can't solve it.